# Openhardwaremontor.dll function access in VB.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, hardware-interface, hardware

I am trying to use Openhardwaremonitor.dll to read CPU temperature, but not able to get it right.

```
If cp. = SensorType.Temperature Then
                    Trace.WriteLine([String].Format("{0} Temperature = {1}", sensor.Name, If(sensor.Value.HasValue, sensor.Value.Value.ToString(), "no value")))
                End If
```

The Error is saying:

> Error 4   'OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware.Sensor' is not accessible in
>   this context because it is 'Friend'.

however a friend function should be accessible as I've imported the DLL in the program.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways, I get the answer. All we have to make a call to.

```
getCompleteInfo()
```

Rest is on manipulation of the output.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inherit Friend variables from one assembly to another. Try making `OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware.Sensor` Public.

Comment: Hi, I may not be able to do that as 'OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware.Sensor' is pre compiled in DLL from Open Hardware Monitor. Is there any other way or may be Function in the DLL

Comment: Here's an example of Open Hardware Monitor using C#, with declarations -- maybe that will help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495430/how-can-i-use-open-hardware-monitor-source-code-in-c-sharp-i-tried-anything-do